# Not sufficiently instantiated for maplist(all_distinct, list)

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd, declarative-programming

I'm not able to run this code, what exactly do I have to say about the list to allow `maplist/2` to run `all_distinct/1`?

```
Solution = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I], 
Solution ins 1..9, 
maplist(all_distinct, Solution).
```

I get `ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`.  I understand that I'm not telling it enough about the list of numbers, but I don't know what I need to tell it.  I want a list of 9 different numbers 1 through 9.

Here's a trace when I try to execute:

```
   Call: (7) puzzle(_G548) ? creep
   Call: (8) _G548=[_G656, _G659, _G662, _G665, _G668, _G671, _G674, _G677|...] ? creep
   Exit: (8) [_G656, _G659, _G662, _G665, _G668, _G671, _G674, _G677|...]=[_G656, _G659, _G662, _G665, _G668, _G671, _G674, _G677|...] ? creep
   Call: (8) clpfd: ([_G656, _G659, _G662, _G665, _G668, _G671, _G674|...]ins 1..9) ? creep
   Call: (9) error:must_be(list, [_G656, _G659, _G662, _G665, _G668, _G671, _G674|...]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) error:must_be(list, [_G656, _G659, _G662, _G665, _G668, _G671, _G674|...]) ? creep
   Call: (9) clpfd:'__aux_maplist/2_fd_variable+0'([_G656, _G659, _G662, _G665, _G668, _G671, _G674|...]) ? creep
   Call: (10) clpfd:fd_variable(_G656) ? creep
   Call: (11) var(_G656) ? creep
   Exit: (11) var(_G656) ? creep
   Call: (11) true ? creep
   Exit: (11) true ? creep
   Exit: (10) clpfd:fd_variable(_G656) ? creep
   Call: (10) clpfd:'__aux_maplist/2_fd_variable+0'([_G659, _G662, _G665, _G668, _G671, _G674, _G677|...]) ? creep
```

It looks like `ins/2` might be not working and then still passing off to `maplist/2`?  I've got no idea what is happening.

Comment: Actually, a `type_error(list,X)` would have been more helpful

Comment: @false You should probably report this as a bug

Comment: @Boris: Filed 2013-08-08 as i3a#314. But it is a very hairy situation, since a variable is commonly not associated with a type error. Yes, there is no instance that would be a valid term, so a type error seems to make a lot of sense, but it still is on the edge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is that you are making a list of variables, `Solutions`, and then `Solutions ins 1..9` makes *each* variable an integer between 1 and 9.

`all_distinct/1` expects a list, not an integer.

So, if you want a list of 9 *distinct* integers:

```
?- Solutions = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I],
   Solutions ins 1..9,
   all_distinct(Solutions).
L = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I],
A in 1..9,
all_distinct([A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H|...]),
B in 1..9,
C in 1..9,
D in 1..9,
E in 1..9,
F in 1..9,
G in 1..9,
H in 1..9,
I in 1..9.
```